# Monitor and time a process that is already running and saving the total running time into a file

Tags: command-line, bash, process, ps, htop

I have a few different processes that have been running for quite a long time (200 h). I just realized that I have forgotten to use the `time` command to get the total running time at the end.

These are the processes I am interested in:

```
$ pidof perl
5897 5895 5890 5885 5797
```

These processes are currently running and once they finish I want to know how long it had taken them to finish.

Is there any way to track these processes and save the total running time once they are done? Or is this sort of information retained somewhere by Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you know the exact start time, so that we only need to capture when they finish and do the maths? Or is the start time unknown?

Comment: Well, that information is available in `ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd | grep perl`. So yes, I do know the exact start time for each process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have root access, you can attach `strace` to them and see when exactly they exit. For example, I ran `sleep 1m` on one terminal, and in another:

```
% sudo strace -ttte exit_group -p $(pgrep sleep -n)
strace: Process 11637 attached
1520303315.074384 exit_group(0)         = ?
1520303315.074525 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

The [`strace` options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/strace.1.html):

```
-t         Prefix each line of the trace with the time of day.

-tt        If  given  twice,  the time printed will include the
           microseconds.

-ttt       If given thrice, the time printed will  include  the
           microseconds and the leading portion will be printed
           as the number of seconds since the epoch.

-e expr    A  qualifying expression which modifies which events
           to trace or how to trace them.
```

You can attach multiple PIDs with `strace`, so something like:

```
sudo strace -ttte exit_group -p "$(pidof perl)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can monitor a running process with e.g. PID 12345 and determine its total run time in seconds once it exited like this:

```bsh
startdate="$(ps -o lstart= 12345)" 
while ps 12345 &>/dev/null ; do sleep 1 ; done 
bc <<< "$(date +%s) - $(date -d "$startdate" +%s)"
```

This first reads the `lstart` property of the process using `ps` which contains the exact start date as string. We have to remember this while the process is still running and store it in a shell variable named `startdate`.

Then we wait while the process is still running by checking the status of `ps 12345` every second, as it will exit with a non-zero status if no matching process was found.

Once the process exited, we subtract the start time from the current time, both converted to seconds since Epoch, using `bc` and see the result as time span in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the user and system time consumed of a running process from the /proc/$pid/stat file.  For example, if you want to get the user time from process 3628, use:

```
echo "scale=2; $(cat /proc/3628/stat | cut -d' ' -f14) / $(getconf CLK_TCK)" | bc
```

..the above extracts field 14 (user time in clock ticks) and divides this by the clock tick rate to calculate the user time in seconds to 2 decimal places.

For the system time, use field 15, e.g.:

```
echo "scale=2; $(cat /proc/3628/stat | cut -d' ' -f15) / $(getconf CLK_TCK)" | bc
```

Here is one solution that assigns shell variables:

```
PID=1327
USRTIME=`echo "scale=2; $(cat /proc/$PID/stat | cut -d' ' -f14) / $(getconf CLK_TCK)" | bc`
SYSTIME=`echo "scale=2; $(cat /proc/$PID/stat | cut -d' ' -f15) / $(getconf CLK_TCK)" | bc`
echo "Time: USR: $USRTIME SYS: $SYSTIME"
```